# Biber cannot cite multiple references - ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \blx@tempb

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, biber

Since I updated MiKTeX I have been having issues when compiling my references.
It works fine If I only cite one reference e.g. `\cite{a}` but when I want to cite multiple references e.g. `\cite{a, b, c}` I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@tempb 

l.243 ...\cite{Verre2012a, Verre2012b, Verre2011}.

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I have tried deleting all the generated files -> does not work

I have tried reinstalling MiKTeX, Texmaker -> does not work

I have tried looking for a solution only -> nothing related showed up

Here's is the settings I use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage{chemist}    
\usepackage{titletoc}   
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}    
\usepackage{pgf}        
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}      
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{verbatim}   %\begin{comment} \end{comment}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}    
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
    tikznode boxed title,
    enhanced,
    arc=0mm,
    interior style={white},
    attach boxed title to top center= {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={size=normal,colframe=white,boxrule=0pt},
    title={#1}}
\usepackage[backend=biber ,natbib=true ,style=ieee,defernumbers=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Chapters/Chapter_introduction/chap_intro.bib}
\include{Chapters/Chapter_introduction/chap_intro}
```

Here is a snippet of the .bib file

```
@article{Verre2012a,
author = {Verre, R. and Fleischer, K. and Ualibek, O. and Shvets, I. V.},
journal = {Applied Physics Letters},
number = {3},
title = {{Self-assembled broadband plasmonic nanoparticle arrays for sensing applications}},
volume = {100},
year = {2012}
}

@article{Verre2012b,
author = {Verre, R and Fleischer, K and McGilp, J F and Fox, D and Behan, G and Zhang, H and Shvets, I V},
journal = {Nanotechnology},
number = {3},
pages = {035606},
title = {{Controlled in situ growth of tunable plasmonic self-assembled nanoparticle arrays}},
volume = {23},
year = {2012}
}

@article{Verre2012,
author = {Verre, R. and Fleischer, K. and Ualibek, O. and Shvets, I. V.},
journal = {Applied Physics Letters},
number = {3},
pages = {031102},
title = {{Self-assembled broadband plasmonic nanoparticle arrays for sensing applications}},
volume = {100},
year = {2012}
}
```

Again it worked fine before the update, which was something like MiKTeX 2.9.6600, and the new one is 2.9.6753. I use Texmaker.

I hope this is enough information.

Thanks in advance

## EDIT 1

After looking at the comments I tried the example from [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/697).

It works fine with `style=numeric-comp` but not with `style=ieee`.

So you might be able to reproduce the error by trying

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article {a,
    title = {A title},
    auhtor = {A. Author},
    year = {2000},
}
@article {b,
    title = {B title},
    auhtor = {B. Author},
    year = {2000},
} 
@article {c,
    title = {C title},
    auhtor = {C. Author},
    year = {2000},
} 
@article {d,
    title = {D title},
    auhtor = {D. Author},
    year = {2000},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
style=ieee
]{biblatex}

\addglobalbib{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefsection
\cite{a, b}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A.]
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
\cite{c, d}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B.]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## EDIT 2

I am not sure if this is the correct place to show a more precise example, but I have been testing and here is a full example which does not compile for me

The files are in the correct folder and what happens is if I comment either includes e.g. `%\include{Chapters/Chapter_tech_exp/chap_tech_exp}`. It works as expected.

If I comment the multiple citations e.g. multiple citations `%\cite{Harden1959,Wagner2000, Aspnes1988}.` in the *second* file, it works, but not if I comment it only in the first file.

And finally if I remove the style i.e. `\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=false]{biblatex}` It works as well.

I am clueless ...

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, defernumbers=false]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{
\section*{References for Chapter \ref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
\addbibresource{Bib-main.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}


\begin{document}

\include{Chapters/Chapter_introduction/chap_intro}
\include{Chapters/Chapter_tech_exp/chap_tech_exp}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### `chap_tech_exp.tex`

```
\section{Reflective and transmission anisotropy spectroscopy (RAS, TAS)}
\begin{refsection}
single citation \cite{Harden1959}, \cite{Wagner2000}.
multiple citations \cite{Harden1959,Wagner2000, Aspnes1988}. 
\newpage
\newrefcontext[labelprefix= \romannumeral \therefsection]
\printbibliography[section=\therefsection, heading=subbibnumbered]
\end{refsection}
```

#### `chap_intro.tex`

```
\section{First observations of surface plasmon resonance}
\begin{refsection}
single citation \cite{Harden1959}, \cite{Wagner2000}.
multiple citations \cite{Harden1959,Wagner2000, Aspnes1988}. 

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=\romannumeral \therefsection]
\printbibliography[section=\therefsection, heading=subbibnumbered]
\end{refsection}
```

#### `Bib-main.bib`

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@Article{Aspnes1988,
  author  = {Aspnes, D E and Harbison, J. P. and Studna, A. A. and Florez, L. T.},
  title   = {{Reflectance difference spectroscopy system for real time measurements of crystal growth}},
  journal = {Applied Physics Letters},
  year    = {1988},
  volume  = {52},
  number  = {12},
  pages   = {957--959},
}


@article{Weightman2005,
author = {Weightman, P and Martin, D S and Cole, R J and Farrell, T},
journal = {Reports on Progress in Physics},
number = {6},
pages = {1251--1341},
title = {{Reflection anisotropy spectroscopy}},
volume = {68},
year = {2005}
}


@article{Wagner2000,
author = {Wagner, F E and Haslbeck, S and Stievano, L and Calogero, S and Pankhurst, Q a and Martinek, K P},
journal = {Nature},
number = {6805},
pages = {691--692},
title = {{Before striking gold in gold-ruby glass}},
volume = {407},
year = {2000}
}

@article{Harden1959,
author = {Harden, D. B. and Toynbee, Jocelyn M. C.},
journal = {Archaeologia},
number = {December 1954},
pages = {179--212},
title = {{VII.The Rothschild Lycurgus Cup}},
volume = {97},
year = {1959}
}
```

#### Log file when it does NOT work

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6730 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.10)  10 JUL 2018 17:06
entering extended mode
**./test3.tex
(test3.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\refcount.sty"
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
))))
\c@section@level=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 355.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 355.
)
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2018/03/04 v3.11 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count90

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex
\@xs@message=\write3
\integerpart=\count91
\decimalpart=\count92
)
Package: xstring 2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count93
\c@listtotal=\count94
\c@listcount=\count95
\c@liststart=\count96
\c@liststop=\count97
\c@citecount=\count98
\c@citetotal=\count99
\c@multicitecount=\count100
\c@multicitetotal=\count101
\c@instcount=\count102
\c@maxnames=\count103
\c@minnames=\count104
\c@maxitems=\count105
\c@minitems=\count106
\c@citecounter=\count107
\c@savedcitecounter=\count108
\c@uniquelist=\count109
\c@uniquename=\count110
\c@refsection=\count111
\c@refsegment=\count112
\c@maxextratitle=\count113
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count114
\c@maxextradate=\count115
\c@maxextraalpha=\count116
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count117
\c@highnamepenalty=\count118
\c@lownamepenalty=\count119
\c@maxparens=\count120
\c@parenlevel=\count121
\blx@tempcnta=\count122
\blx@tempcntb=\count123
\blx@tempcntc=\count124
\blx@maxsection=\count125
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count126
\blx@notetype=\count127
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count128
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count129
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count130
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\biblabelsep=\skip45
\bibitemsep=\skip46
\bibnamesep=\skip47
\bibinitsep=\skip48
\bibparsep=\skip49
\bibhang=\skip50
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write4
\c@mincomprange=\count131
\c@maxcomprange=\count132
\c@mincompwidth=\count133
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count134
\c@savedafterword=\count135
\c@annotator=\count136
\c@savedannotator=\count137
\c@author=\count138
\c@savedauthor=\count139
\c@bookauthor=\count140
\c@savedbookauthor=\count141
\c@commentator=\count142
\c@savedcommentator=\count143
\c@editor=\count144
\c@savededitor=\count145
\c@editora=\count146
\c@savededitora=\count147
\c@editorb=\count148
\c@savededitorb=\count149
\c@editorc=\count150
\c@savededitorc=\count151
\c@foreword=\count152
\c@savedforeword=\count153
\c@holder=\count154
\c@savedholder=\count155
\c@introduction=\count156
\c@savedintroduction=\count157
\c@namea=\count158
\c@savednamea=\count159
\c@nameb=\count160
\c@savednameb=\count161
\c@namec=\count162
\c@savednamec=\count163
\c@translator=\count164
\c@savedtranslator=\count165
\c@shortauthor=\count166
\c@savedshortauthor=\count167
\c@shorteditor=\count168
\c@savedshorteditor=\count169
\c@labelname=\count170
\c@savedlabelname=\count171
\c@institution=\count172
\c@savedinstitution=\count173
\c@lista=\count174
\c@savedlista=\count175
\c@listb=\count176
\c@savedlistb=\count177
\c@listc=\count178
\c@savedlistc=\count179
\c@listd=\count180
\c@savedlistd=\count181
\c@liste=\count182
\c@savedliste=\count183
\c@listf=\count184
\c@savedlistf=\count185
\c@location=\count186
\c@savedlocation=\count187
\c@organization=\count188
\c@savedorganization=\count189
\c@origlocation=\count190
\c@savedoriglocation=\count191
\c@origpublisher=\count192
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count193
\c@publisher=\count194
\c@savedpublisher=\count195
\c@language=\count196
\c@savedlanguage=\count197
\c@origlanguage=\count198
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count199
\c@pageref=\count266
\c@savedpageref=\count267
\shorthandwidth=\skip51
\shortjournalwidth=\skip52
\shortserieswidth=\skip53
\shorttitlewidth=\skip54
\shortauthorwidth=\skip55
\shorteditorwidth=\skip56
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip57
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip58
\localshorthandwidth=\skip59
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip60
\localshortserieswidth=\skip61
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip62
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip63
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip64
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count268
\c@textcitetotal=\count269
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count270
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count271
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count272
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count273
\c@smartand=\count274
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'ieee'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex-ieee\ieee.bbx
File: ieee.bbx 2017/03/27 v1.2d biblatex bibliography style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric-comp'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\numeric-com
p.bbx
File: numeric-comp.bbx 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bb
x
File: standard.bbx 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count275
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count276
))))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'ieee'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee.cbx' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex-ieee\ieee.cbx
File: ieee.cbx 2017/03/27 v1.2d biblatex citation style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric-comp'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.cbx' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\numeric-com
p.cbx
File: numeric-comp.cbx 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
\c@cbx@tempcnta=\count277
\c@cbx@tempcntb=\count278
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.sty
Package: csquotes 2018/04/13 v5.2d context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
\csq@reset=\count279
\csq@gtype=\count280
\csq@glevel=\count281
\csq@qlevel=\count282
\csq@maxlvl=\count283
\csq@tshold=\count284
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks17

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.def
File: csquotes.def 2018/04/13 v5.2d csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
)
Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.cfg
File: csquotes.cfg 
)
Package csquotes Info: Enabling multilingual quotes.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(C:\Users\william\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2018/03/04 v3.11 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... none found.


Package csquotes Warning: No multilingual support.
(csquotes)                Cannot enable multilingual quotes on input line 16.

(test3.aux (Chapters/Chapter_introduction/chap_intro.aux)
(Chapters/Chapter_tech_exp/chap_tech_exp.aux))
\openout1 = `test3.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout4 = `test3.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test3.bbl' found.
 (test3.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 16.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 16.
\openout2 = `Chapters/Chapter_introduction/chap_intro.aux'.


(Chapters/Chapter_introduction/chap_intro.tex
Overfull \hbox (1.08336pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--3
[]\T1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 First ob-ser-va-tions of sur-face plas-mon res-o-nance 
 []

\blx@maxsegment@1=\count285
\blx@sectionciteorder@1=\count286
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=1 on input line 4.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsection:1' on input line 4.

Package biblatex Warning: Option 'labelprefix' requires global
(biblatex)                'defernumbers=true' on input line 9.


Package biblatex Warning: Option 'resetnumbers' requires 'defernumbers=true'.
(biblatex)                Ignoring 'resetnumbers=true' on input line 9.

Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 10.
) [1


{C:/Users/william/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
\openout2 = `Chapters/Chapter_tech_exp/chap_tech_exp.aux'.


(Chapters/Chapter_tech_exp/chap_tech_exp.tex
\blx@maxsegment@2=\count287
\blx@sectionciteorder@2=\count288
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=2 on input line 6.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsection:2' on input line 6.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@tempb 

l.8 ...s \cite{Harden1959,Wagner2000, Aspnes1988}.

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[2


]

Package biblatex Warning: Option 'labelprefix' requires global
(biblatex)                'defernumbers=true' on input line 11.


Package biblatex Warning: Option 'resetnumbers' requires 'defernumbers=true'.
(biblatex)                Ignoring 'resetnumbers=true' on input line 11.

Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 12.
) [3]

Package biblatex Warning: Option 'resetnumbers' requires 'defernumbers=true'.
(biblatex)                Ignoring 'resetnumbers=true' on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 21.

(test3.aux (Chapters/Chapter_introduction/chap_intro.aux)
(Chapters/Chapter_tech_exp/chap_tech_exp.aux))

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test3
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test3.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test3.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8398 strings out of 492973
 151904 string characters out of 3135926
 572657 words of memory out of 3000000
 12203 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 8172 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 47i,4n,47p,855b,1219s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\william\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi60
0\ecti1000.pk> <C:\Users\william\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknap
pen\ec\dpi600\ecbx1200.pk> <C:\Users\william\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\
ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1000.pk> <C:\Users\william\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2
.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecbx1440.pk>
Output written on test3.pdf (3 pages, 45208 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 149 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately the code you have shown so far is not nearly enough to reproduce your problem. Please post a full, yet minimal document (with `\begin{document}...\end{document}` and example `.bib` entries) that reproduces your error. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and specifically for bibliographies [How to write a MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: That is still not an MWE in the sense of the two links in my comment above. We will only be able to help you with this swiftly and efficiently if you can help us by providing a proper code example, so please follow the links, read them and edit your question accordingly. If I take the code you have shown so far and complete it so it compiles for me **I can not reproduce the error**. Can you reproduce the error even in a small example like https://gist.github.com/moewew/778d707ccd4594bbe7790813d1f3d77a?

Comment: Do you an error with the example here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/697. If yes your biblatex and biber is not up-to-date. Run in the miktex console (user and admin) the update manager.

Comment: I have tried Ulrike Fischer's example and it works. It thus allowed me to pin down the probleme with the issue being the style, which worked when `style=numeric-comp` but not when `style=ieee`.

Comment: The MWE as posted compiles fine for me and gives the expected output. Before we are setting off to a wild goose chase: Can you reproduce your problem in an even smaller document? Do you for example need the `\newrefcontext` or `\newrefsection` lines in the MWE? Can you compile https://gist.github.com/moewew/778d707ccd4594bbe7790813d1f3d77a?

Comment: The example works fine for me. Show your log-file and the blg-file.

Comment: The problem is that `\blx@tempb` is a generic temporary variable that is used quite often (~144 times alone in `biblatex.sty`), so it is important to make the example that reproduces the error as short as possible to help with the investigation. So please try to remove everything from the example that is not needed to reproduce the error (my hope would be the `\newrefcontext` and `\newrefsection`s). Then add `\listfiles` to the very top of your document and compile as far as possible and show us the `.log` and `.blg` files.

Comment: Any news here? Could you reduce your example further and can you show us the `.log` and `.blg` files?

Comment: not enough space in the edit for the blg file, where should I put it?

Comment: Never mind the `.blg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams, yet again that @moewe has solved the problem !

I my case, using `\newrefsection` instead of `\begin{refsection} ... \end{refsection}` only worked on small projects with the large project showing memory saturation when compiling.

The solution was therefore to substitute `\begin{refsection} ... \end{refsection}` with `\begingroup\newrefsection ... \endrefsection\endgroup` and the whole document compiles even with `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee,defernumbers=false]{biblatex}`, an include now typically looks like this

```
\chapter{tile}
\label{chapter_label}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\startcontents[chapter_label]
\printcontents[chapter_label]{}{1}{}
\begingroup\newrefsection

... \cite{a, b}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[section=\therefsection, heading=subbibnumbered]
\endrefsection\endgroup
\stopcontents[chapter_label]
```

and I can have multiple includes with multiple reference citations and all works well... for now.

thanks

Comment: Did the fix `\makeatletter
\protected\def\endrefsection{% 
   \endrefcontext
   \blx@endrefsection 
   \blx@inf@refsec} 
\makeatother` proposed in my answer not work for you?

Comment: ... I should have added that that would be used as `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}`, so you would not have to change your document at all.

Comment: No it didn't, I still got a memory error with and without the use of `\endrefsection`, but your last solution works like a charm. I don't know if these two solutions e.i. `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` and the `\begingroup\newrefsection ... \endrefsection\endgroup` are meant to be analogous, but the latter works for me. :)

Comment: Well in theory `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` together with my fixed `\endrefsection` should be equivalent to `\begingroup\newrefsection...\endrefsection\endgroup`, but what do I know.

Comment: I'll test and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

> This was about a bug in `biblatex` that has been resolved in version 3.12. Update your TeX system in case you experience this issue.
>
> The answer below is kept for historical interest.

This MWE reproduces the issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
single citation \cite{sigfridsson}, \cite{nussbaum}.
multiple citations \cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum, worman}. 
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
single citation \cite{sigfridsson}, \cite{nussbaum}.
multiple citations \cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum, worman}. 

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

The problem is related to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/697. In fact it is the same issue just with `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` instead of `\newrefsection`.

As a workaround until the problem is fixed, use `\newrefsection` instead of `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}`. This is not entirely equivalent in all cases, but should hopefully work for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\newrefsection
single citation \cite{sigfridsson}, \cite{nussbaum}.
multiple citations \cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum, worman}. 
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
single citation \cite{sigfridsson}, \cite{nussbaum}.
multiple citations \cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum, worman}. 

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

In the comments you mentioned issues with `\newrefcontext`, you can try a different workaround, my first suggestion would be

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\endrefsection{% 
   \endrefcontext
   \blx@endrefsection 
   \blx@inf@refsec} 
\makeatother
```

Add this to your preamble after you load `biblatex`.

Comment: It works on the small example. However, on my large project, substituting \begin{refsection} with the\nextrefsection leads to a memory saturation. I don't really have time to send the example script but basically I use `\startcontents[chap]  
\printcontents[chap]{}{1}{}
\begin{refsection}` at the begining of the include and `\newpage
\newrefcontext[labelprefix= \therefsection]
\printbibliography[section=\therefsection, heading=subbibnumbered]
\end{refsection}
\stopcontents[chap]`at the end. It also works on the small example but not on my manuscript. i'll keep in touch thanks

Comment: I think the memory error comes from the fact that I use pgf files which includes images (png), nevertheless, when using `\begin{refsection}` the memory is not exceed whereas it is when using `\newrefsection`

Comment: @will.mendil Odd..., please try to break that down to a minimal example that shows the problem. I have added another possible workaround, please test it.

Comment: I apologise for such a simple question, but where should I insert the `\protected....` code?

Comment: @will.mendil In the preamble after you load `biblatex`. You will also need a `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

Comment: @will.mendil Since `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` is slightly different way of saying `\begingroup\newrefsection ... \endgroup` you could also try the latter (or `\begingroup\newrefsection ... \endrefsection\endgroup`). Anyway, do let me know if any of this (and what!) works for you.

Comment: I just posted the answer as what you have proposed worked, however, I just realised, should have I let you post the answer so you would get the stackexchange rewards?