# Print everything from an auxiliary bib resource, with different sorting options

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to do something that I'm sure it's possible to do with BibLaTeX and Biber, but I'm struggling to figure it out. So, I have two `.bib` files, `mystuff.bib` and `otherstuff.bib`. Throughout the document, `otherstuff.bib` entries are cited, and they should be output in the `\printbibliography` at the end of the document. But: during the document, I need a section which contains everything listed in `mystuff.bib` (accessed by `\nocite{*}`) sorted using `ydnt` rather than the normal `nyt`. I can get a section with all of `mystuff.bib` by using the following:

```
\begin{refsection}[mystuff.bib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
```

But, I don't have individual control over how it is sorted. I've tried using `\addsectionbib` but I'm not sure I understand how to use it to achieve what I want.

So. I want two bibliographies, using different bibresources, and different sorting options, within one document. How?

Comment: Try `\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]` before the `\printbibliography`. (Untested because a full MWE is missing.)

Comment: That appears to work. Thanks! If you could turn that into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the sorting by switching to a different `refcontext`. You may want to try

```
\begin{refsection}[mystuff.bib]
\nocite{*}
\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
```

Comment: I had to make use of the workarounds in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440084/215) to make this work in the actual use case.

Comment: @Seamus At least with an up-to-date system you shouldn't have to, but without a full MWE and more detailed description of what you want to do I can not investigate the issue further, I'm afraid.